# Why does my labview client program not receive the 1-d array sent by the labview server program over TCP?

Tags: tcp, labview

the server is executed first, followed by the client.

The client attempts to initiate a TCP connection with the server.  As soon as server detects it a "connection ID" is created.

The server attempts to send a "setup" packet to the client by building an array of numbers.

Server labview code

[image]

Client labview code
[image]

Setup Packet creation code:

[image]

Comment: What error do you receive on the client side? Have you checked firewalls?

Comment: @TonPlomp - I get a status code of 0, which, if I understand correctly means no error. I posted this same question on on the labview website and somebody else was able to execute my code successfully without any changes.  So you are probably right about the firewall. I will check on it. Thanks!

Comment: Well you should get a timeout on the server or an error or get the data on the client.

Comment: @TonPlomp - You are correct. I turned off my firewall and it worked perfectly.  I would award you points but looks like the community has closed this question.

Comment: I am wondering why this question is closed. IMHO it's on topic.

Comment: It's open again. However I would advise you to rewrite the question. Make the example code shots cleaner, and as small as possible. No need for the subVI in the client code. Your code should have failed with just one numeric. And always show/tell the errors you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to turn off your firewall, the code looks valid to me.